# Error : Unexpected null value in flutter when I run app after flutter validator

Tags: flutter, dart

when I use if statement to validate error appears talking about this if statement:
(entire code at end)

```
 movetoHome(BuildContext context) async {
    if (_formKey.currentState!.validate()) {
      setState(() {
        changebutton = true;
      });
      await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 1));
      await Navigator.pushNamed(context, Myroutes.homeRoute);
      setState(() {
        changebutton = false;
      });
    }
}
```

All of the errors below appears when i click on button which is using this

```
onTap: () => movetoHome(context),
```

Wrapped by Inkwell Class.

1. If I run using f5 it takes me to breaking point in feedback.dart at
   line 107

   return Future.value();
2. if I run using terminal it gives me this error:

   Error: Unexpected null value.
   at Object.throw_ [as throw] (http://localhost:53848/dart_sdk.js:5348:11)
   at Object.nullCheck (http://localhost:53848/dart_sdk.js:5681:30)
   at login_page._LoginPageState.new.movetoHome (http://localhost:53848/packages/learning/pages/login_page.dart.lib.js:644:28)
   at movetoHome.next ()
   at runBody (http://localhost:53848/dart_sdk.js:39250:34)
   at Object._async [as async] (http://localhost:53848/dart_sdk.js:39281:7)
   at login_page._LoginPageState.new.movetoHome (http://localhost:53848/packages/learning/pages/login_page.dart.lib.js:643:20)
   at http://localhost:53848/packages/learning/pages/login_page.dart.lib.js:677:569
   at ink_well._InkResponseState.new.[_handleTap] (http://localhost:53848/packages/flutter/src/material/icon_button.dart.lib.js:50393:31)
   at tap.TapGestureRecognizer.new.invokeCallback (http://localhost:53848/packages/flutter/src/gestures/recognizer.dart.lib.js:194:18)
   at tap.TapGestureRecognizer.new.handleTapUp (http://localhost:53848/packages/flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart.lib.js:408:40)
   at tap.TapGestureRecognizer.new.[_checkUp] (http://localhost:53848/packages/flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart.lib.js:214:12)
   at tap.TapGestureRecognizer.new.handlePrimaryPointer (http://localhost:53848/packages/flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart.lib.js:160:23)
   at tap.TapGestureRecognizer.new.handleEvent (http://localhost:53848/packages/flutter/src/gestures/recognizer.dart.lib.js:449:16)
   at pointer_router.PointerRouter.new.[_dispatch] (http://localhost:53848/packages/flutter/src/gestures/pointer_router.dart.lib.js:93:9)
   at http://localhost:53848/packages/flutter/src/gestures/pointer_router.dart.lib.js:128:26
   at LinkedMap.new.forEach (http://localhost:53848/dart_sdk.js:26346:11)
   at pointer_router.PointerRouter.new.[_dispatchEventToRoutes]
   (http://localhost:53848/packages/flutter/src/gestures/pointer_router.dart.lib.js:125:29)
   at pointer_router.PointerRouter.new.route (http://localhost:53848/packages/flutter/src/gestures/pointer_router.dart.lib.js:117:37)
   at binding$5.WidgetsFlutterBinding.new.handleEvent (http://localhost:53848/packages/flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart.lib.js:389:26)
   at binding$5.WidgetsFlutterBinding.new.dispatchEvent (http://localhost:53848/packages/flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart.lib.js:372:24)
   at binding$5.WidgetsFlutterBinding.new.dispatchEvent (http://localhost:53848/packages/flutter/src/rendering/layer.dart.lib.js:5376:13)
   at binding$5.WidgetsFlutterBinding.new.[_handlePointerEventImmediately]
   (http://localhost:53848/packages/flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart.lib.js:343:14)
   at binding$5.WidgetsFlutterBinding.new.handlePointerEvent
   (http://localhost:53848/packages/flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart.lib.js:316:43)
   at binding$5.WidgetsFlutterBinding.new.[_flushPointerEventQueue]
   (http://localhost:53848/packages/flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart.lib.js:305:14)
   at binding$5.WidgetsFlutterBinding.new.[_handlePointerDataPacket]
   (http://localhost:53848/packages/flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart.lib.js:295:65)
   at Object.invoke1 (http://localhost:53848/dart_sdk.js:186355:7)
   at _engine.EnginePlatformDispatcher..invokeOnPointerDataPacket (http://localhost:53848/dart_sdk.js:166281:15)
   at _engine.PointerBinding..[_onPointerData] (http://localhost:53848/dart_sdk.js:166941:49)
   at http://localhost:53848/dart_sdk.js:167399:28
   at http://localhost:53848/dart_sdk.js:167352:16
   at http://localhost:53848/dart_sdk.js:167045:11

My login page entire code :

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:learning/pages/utis/routes.dart';

class LoginPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const LoginPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _LoginPageState createState() => _LoginPageState();
}

class _LoginPageState extends State<LoginPage> {
  String name = "";
  bool changebutton = false;
  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();



 movetoHome(BuildContext context) {
    if (_formKey.currentState!.validate()) {
      print("before if");

  setState(() {
    changebutton = true;
    print("Change button 1");
  });
  Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 1));
  print("while await");
  Navigator.pushNamed(context, Myroutes.homeRoute);
  print("after Naviagtor");
  setState(() {
    changebutton = false;
  });
}


}



Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        body: Form(
          child: SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Column(
              children: [
                Image.asset(
                  "assets/images/login_image.png",
                  fit: BoxFit.cover,
                ),
                SizedBox(height: 10),
                Text(
                  "Welcome $name",
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 25,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    color: Colors.black,
                  ),
                ),
                Padding(
                  padding:
                      const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 40, vertical: 30),
                  child: Column(
                    key: _formKey,
                    children: [
                      TextFormField(
                        validator: (value) {
                          if (value!.isEmpty) {
                            return "Username cannot be empty";
                          }

               

   return null;
                    },
                        decoration: InputDecoration(
                          labelText: "Username",
                          hintText: "Enter Username",
                        ),
                        onChanged: (value) {
                          name = value;
                          setState(() {});
                        },
                      ),
                      TextFormField(
                        validator: (value) {
                          if (value!.isEmpty) {
                            return "Password cant be Empty";
                          } else if (value.length < 6) {
                            return "Password should be greater the 6 ";
                          }
                          return null;
                        },
                        obscureText: true,
                        decoration: InputDecoration(
                          labelText: "Password",
                          hintText: "Enter password",
                        ),
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
                Material(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(changebutton ? 80 : 10),
                  color: Colors.purple,
                  child: InkWell(
                    onTap: () => movetoHome(context),
                    child: AnimatedContainer(
                      duration: Duration(
                        seconds: 1,
                      ),
                      alignment: Alignment.center,
                      child: changebutton
                          ? Icon(
                              Icons.check,
                              color: Colors.white,
                            )
                          : Text(
                              "Login",
                              style: TextStyle(
                                color: Colors.white,
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                fontSize: 16,
                              ),
                            ),
                      height: 40,
                      width: changebutton ? 40 : 100,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ));
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you write print statements after each line in the `movetoHome` method to see exactly where the code breaks?

Comment: @Nicks101 I used print statement but no output I also used print statement before if statement but again no output however as I remove if statement everything start to work without error other then validation.

Comment: Can you show the code where `_formKey` is used (assignment, declaration, etc)?

Comment: @Nicks101                                                                                                                                     child: Column(
                    key: _formKey,
                    children: [
                      TextFormField(
                        validator: (value) {
                          if (value!.isEmpty) {
                            return "Username cannot be empty";
                          }

                          return null;
                        },

Comment: @Nicks101 BTW, I am sharing my whole code on question's description as i cant share whole code here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Widget where `_formKey` is assigned is wrong.

It should be assigned to key property of `Form`, not any other Widget.

```dart
Form(
  key: _formKey, //// Assign here
)
```

Refer flutter official docs [here](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/forms/validation#1-create-a-form-with-a-globalkey)

Comment: perfect thanks buddy , small mistake was messing with me for past 4 hrs.